# Windows Sometimes Renames Network Adapter

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7

I am running Windows 7 Embedded with a locked boot partition (meaning the registry and entire OS is in the same state at every boot).

This device uses statically defined IP addresses, which are assigned to the Ethernet port, normally named "Local Area Connection"

The odd behavior is that sometimes when Windows boots (about 1 in 20 times), it renames this adapter to "Local Area Connection 2" or even "Local Area Connection 3", and as a result, the specified static IP configuration settings are not applied.

What could be causing this? How does Windows identify its network adapters that would cause the OS to think it has a new adapter installed?

Comment: Also, I was not sure if this question is better for ServerFault or SuperUser, so it is temporarily cross-posted. I will delete the SU post if I can get some activity here.

Comment: Windows enumerates the hardware tree on every boot and upon detecting new hardware will attempt to install the drivers for the hardware via PNP. Whenever a new NIC is detected the drivers are installed (if available) and a new Local Area Connection is created with a name succeeding the previous or existing Local Area Connection named NICs. It looks to me like Windows is detecting the NIC as a new piece of hardware and that's why it's naming the LAN connection 2, 3, etc. You'll need to figure out why it's doing that.

Comment: @joeqwerty, but how does Windows determine a "new NIC" is detected. What is is using to identify the adapters? Physically the network device is connected via PCI.

Comment: Courtesy of Tim Robinson: Each type of hardware bus (e.g. PCI) has its own driver. At boot time, each bus driver enumerates the devices on its bus. The Windows kernel checks this list against the list of devices it knows about, which allows it to determine which hardware has been recently added. The bus driver gives enough information to Windows to allow Windows to locate a driver for the device, which is then installed. - It would seem that the PCI bus is misreporting the NIC to the Windows kernel. I might suggest checking for and applying any BIOS/chipset drivers that are available.